# GTK3 programs not launching with correct theme or settings (even with config files)

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, i3, theme, gtk3

Currently all my gtk3 apps launch in the standard Adwaita theme. I have been, so far unsuccessfully, trying to get them to launch in the dark variant.

I know this should work beacue when I do `GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark program` the program will launch using the correct theme.

After some googling and checking the arch wiki I found I had to create the following config files, `~/.gtkrc-2.0` for gtk2 programs and `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` for gtk3 pograms. The `~/.gtkrc-2.0`  file contains the following:

`gtk-theme-name = "Adwaita-dark"`

the `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`file conatins:

```
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name=Adwaita:dark
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

I believe this worked because when I use neofetch it has a line stating `Theme: Adwaita-dark [GTK2], Adwaita:dark [GTK3]`yet still gtk3 applications launch in Adwaita and not Adwaita-dark/Adwaita:dark

Additionally I have also tried using the gsettings command, instaling lxappearance, and by adding `export GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark` to my `~/.xinitrc` file. None of these things have worked either.

I am using arch linux with xorg and i3 window manager.
How do I get this to work? All I want is for gtk apps to launch in dark mode. Is there something I am missing? Something I did wrong? Maybe a work around? I honestly did not expect this to be so difficult. Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: So I'm still not sure why it was not working but I just downloaded another theme from the Aur and used that instead. Works fine now!

Comment: Would be helpful if you included which theme that was.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to `~/.xprofile`:

```bsh
export GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark
```