# How to change Qt/Gtk theme using CLI

Tags: gtk, qt, theme, dconf, gsettings

I can change the theme using `lxappearance` and everything works.  This includes `pcmanfm`, `gnome-disks`, `firefox`, and  `qalculate-qt` themes being changed.  Using `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Adwaita"` or using `dconf-editor` doesn't change the theme on the listed test applications.

Following https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323065/234626 I can get `gnome-disks` to change, but not `pcmanfm` or `qalculate-qt`.

Likewise, following https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670600/234626 only works for GTK applications and using an environment variable will not let me create a script to toggle between themes.

`$DESKTOP_SESSION` is not set and running `export | grep gtk` procudes:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/home/user/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkrc-2.0
GTK3_MODULES=xapp-gtk3-module
GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module
```

All I want to be able to do is change between `Adwaita` and `Adwaita-dark` using a the command line the way `lxappearance` works.  I am running Manjaro XFCE edition with XCFE uninstalled.  I launch `xmonad` using `startx` if that is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to modify two config files using shell script (or choose your favorite language for script) - You could parse and modify `gtk-theme-name` settings.

That is, modify config files:

- GTK2: `$GTK2_RC_FILES`
- GTK3: `$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

which contains the following line:

- GTK2: `gtk-theme-name="Adwaita-dark"`
- GTK3: `gtk-theme-name=Adwaita-dark`

and exchange the `Adwaita-dark` part (Or the theme you currently have) with `Adwaita` (Or the theme you want).

Or perhaps you could have predefined theme files, and copy the files onto the above config files through shell script.

Do you want to change theme when a key is pressed? Then it should be doable from xmonad config side - launch the script to change theme, or modify the file directly.

Comment: This worked for all the test programs except `pcmanfm`